# migrating from AngularJS

Tags: angular, angularjs

I am trying to migrate an angularJS project into angular.   I am not sure if there is an equivalent functionality for

`(function() {     'user strict';      angular.module('testModule)         .value('myValue,              {'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'} })();`

I just need to know what should I create in the Angular 15 for .value('myVValue'...).  Should I create a single class or a service?   I am assuming that Angular 15 does not have a VALUE that is similar to angularJS.

I am trying to convert the angularjs app and got stuck on how to convert the angular.module().value().

Comment: Add a provider to your module with the [`useValue`](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#value-providers-usevalue)

Comment: I thank you for the response.  In Angular js, I can do this :
 myValue.fields1='newValue'.  How would I do that with useValue in angular.  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'myValue',
      useValue:  => {
        'field1' : 'value1', 'field2' : ' value2'
      }
    }
  ]

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject('myValue') public thisValue: any
  ) 
 {
     thisValue.field1='newValue';
 }
}

Comment: In AngularJS, I can assign a value to a Value.  Can I do that with useValue?

Comment: Yes, Check the second snippet below the link i posted

Comment: The second snippet copies the value from AppConfig into this.title.  I  need to change the value in the config.title dynamically.  How would you do that?

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('APP_CONFIG') public appConfig: any)
  {
  }

  changeAppConfig()
  {
      this.appConfig.domain  = 'new.com';
  }

}
}

Comment: What is the use of Inject in the example. I can just simply import the APP_CONFIG constant and add it as a member in the component if I just want to use it in the component.

APP_CONFIG is defined in another file called APP_CONFIG.ts
export const APP_CONFIG {'domain' : 'new'};
import { APP_CONFIG } from './models/APP_CONFIG';

export class AppComponent {
  appConfig = APP_CONFIG;
  constructor()
  {
  }
  changeAppConfig()
  {
      this.appConfig.domain  = 'new.com';
  }
}
}

Comment: In Angularjs if the angular.module.value is ONLY used in one component and no where else in the angular application, there is no need to create a provider with useValue because a constant can be defined and imported into the angular componet.

In AngularJS if the angular.module.value is used across several components and controllers, defining a provider in angular with userValue makes sense.

Is this correct?

Comment: `APP_CONFIG` is not a constant, It's a provider (or `InjectionToken`). Feel free to `console.log` it. It'll show you that it's a `StaticProvider` or smth like that

Comment: `@Inject` indicates to the angular runtime that there's a dependency which angular cannot resolve (because its type is `Object`, `string` or ...). The decorator allows you to specify which provider you want to inject. It's not required when injecting services since a service is a class and ends up in the javascript bundle. On top of that, a service can (usually is) be decorated with `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`

Comment: Thank you -  APP_CONFIG can be changed inside a method in the component.  Is that correct?  Most examples that have a provider with usevalue are all constants. Thank you for your help...

Comment: For **"angular runtime configuration"** I would rather [do this](https://imran3.medium.com/runtime-configuration-for-angular-c9d9082e1de3)